# Ray Get Head Node Redis Address

Tags: ray

I would like to run ray on a cluster with multiple nodes. I can only submit non-interactive jobs to the cluster so I'm not sure how to get the redis address in a programatic way while the job is running.

I'm fairly certain that the way to start ray on multiple nodes is something like this:

```
ray start --head

for host in $(srun hostname | grep -v $(hostname)); do
    ssh $host ray start --redis-address=$redis_address
done
```

but I need to know the redis address of the head node. When you start the head node it prints:

```
Started Ray on this node. You can add additional nodes to the cluster by calling

    ray start --redis-address 8.8.8.8:59465

from the node you wish to add. You can connect a driver to the cluster from Python by running

    import ray
    ray.init(redis_address="8.8.8.8:59465")

If you have trouble connecting from a different machine, check that your firewall is configured properly. If you wish to terminate the processes that have been started, run
```

I was planning on catching the output like `ray start --head  &> tee redis_port.txt` and then `grep`ing in `redis_address.txt` to find the redis address but it seems like that part of the output isn't caught in `redis_address.txt` and I looked through all the `.out` and `.err` files in the temp directory created by the ray session and none of them have it either.

There must be some better way to do this. What is the intended way to find the redis port of the head node?

Comment: There are two parts to the redis address. First is the IP address of the head node, which you probably already have programmatically. The second is the Redis port, which you can set using `ray start --head --redis-port=6379`. That way, you'll know what the port is and don't have to capture the output.

Comment: Is it possible that a port will not be open? I was aware that I could specify the `redis-port` but I'm concerned about it crashing due to the port being in use. Choosing a constant port each time seems more prone to error rather than letting `ray` choose.

Comment: It's possible that any particular port could be in use. You could choose a large obscure port number to make that less likely. Whether or not this is a good idea depends on the setting. E.g., if other people are running applications on the same nodes or if it's just you.

Comment: Since I'll be the only user on the nodes I think this should be fine but I guess in the other case you could just keep generating ports until you find one that isn't in use. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in comments thanks to Robert's help [so I'm going to post the code that I used based on his advice.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/4413369)

Seems like the best way is just to pick a constant port. The only potential issue is if another user/process on the same machine is using that same port. In that case you might want to try to generate ports until you find one that isn't in use.

I recommend putting any setup you need for each node into a script with the `ray start` command like so

```
redis_address="$(hostname --ip-address)"
redis_address="$redis_address:59465"

ray start --head --redis-port=59465

for host in $(srun hostname | grep -v $(hostname)); do
    ssh $host ./setup_node.sh $redis_address
done
```

where `setup_node.sh` is

```
# any required setup
# ...

ray start --redis-address=$1
```

You'll need something to get a list of the IP addresses like where I have used `srun hostname` above.